# How to fix my Anaconda environments on Mac?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

This is what my notebook looks like and it's been causing me troubles:

[How Jupyter Notebook starts for me on iTerm2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eR2Ek.png)

[The Jupyter Notebook Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUafw.png)

I'm a newbie to Data Science and recently switched over my MacBook using the Migration Assistant. However, after a couple of days when I tried running Jupyter Notebook from my iTerm2, it didn't seem to work so I decided to uninstall my Anaconda Navigator and re-do everything. However, I've installed and uninstalled this a couple of times and haven't reached a solution. I also looked at removing all anaconda related files from my MacBook using Funter. However, still no success.

As of right now, my Anaconda Navigator opens up and so does the anaconda show up within iTerm2. However, the issue has become that there seems to be no kernel running or found when I open up my Jupyter Notebook from either of the two.

Here's the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/AlyB/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1703, in _execute
    result = await result
  File "/Users/AlyB/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "/Users/AlyB/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/handlers.py", line 69, in post
    model = yield maybe_future(
  File "/Users/AlyB/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/Users/AlyB/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "/Users/AlyB/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 88, in create_session
    kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
  File "/Users/AlyB/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/Users/AlyB/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 742, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "/Users/AlyB/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 100, in start_kernel_for_session
    kernel_id = yield maybe_future(
  File "/Users/AlyB/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 735, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "/Users/AlyB/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/notebook/services/kernels/kernelmanager.py", line 176, in start_kernel
    kernel_id = await maybe_future(self.pinned_superclass.start_kernel(self, **kwargs))
  File "/Users/AlyB/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_client/multikernelmanager.py", line 185, in start_kernel
    km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/AlyB/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_client/manager.py", line 313, in start_kernel
    self.kernel = self._launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
  File "/Users/AlyB/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_client/manager.py", line 220, in _launch_kernel
    return launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
  File "/Users/AlyB/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jupyter_client/launcher.py", line 131, in launch_kernel
    proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/AlyB/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/Users/AlyB/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/AlyB/opt/anaconda3/envs/tf2/bin/python'
```

What can I try to resolve this?

Comment: I used the following and it still didn't seem to work:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43916440/error-loading-jupyter-notebook-extensions

Comment: find where your latest version is installed. Then possibly try to move the contents of "/Users/AlyB/opt/anaconda3/envs/tf2/bin/python" into that

Comment: Thanks @Insula, 
I've got a bunch of files and folders in the folder below along side python but python shows up differently in an app form that I can't run by clicking twice. 
/Users/AlyB/opt/anaconda3/envs/tf2/bin/

This is what the the directory reads? I'm not sure how to fix this :/
/Users/AlyB/opt/anaconda3/python.app